# Does Marathon support automating Qt Controls?

Tags: marathontesting

We have an application which has combination of Java Swing and Qt Controls. This application is about 10 years old. However, still lot of updates are happening into this Application. Can Marathon support the recognition of UI Controls of both Qt and JavaUI?